# How to run the SpeechRecognizer for infinite time or very long time?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a background service that keeps on listening for users' message and invokes an activity if it matches with a particular word. The problem is the SpeechRecognizer is able to hear only for few seconds. I want it to continuously hear until I stop it manually through code. I tried EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS and other related extras. It doesn't work. I tried many stack overflow question. None work

Comment: You can't.  It isn't built that way.  You'd need to request the mic and go from scratch.

Comment: Do you know any code or library that can do this? @Gabe Sechan